# ARM Cortex M3 GPIO Interrupts - One ISR per port with 8 pins - How to handle all pins?

Tags: nested, arm, interrupt, gpio

I'm using the Luminary LM3S8962 micro-controller and its included Library Guide, but this should be relevant to any ARM Cortex-M3s that have Nested Vector Interrupts.

You can only register one interrupt service routine function with an entire GPIO Port. A GPIO port typically has 8 pins on it, each of which can be configured with an interrupt. For each pin, you can test whether or not an interrupt "happened" on it (is pending), right? and for each pin you can clear a pending interrupt, right?

If a pin on the GPIO port triggers the ISR then the processor is in the ISR. Then what happens if another pin on the same port triggers an interrupt while we're in the ISR? We assume the code detects what pins have pending interrupts.
- Is this ISR interrupted and a new one begins, with the same code, but an updated PinInterruptStatus register ? (I hope not)
- Is this ISR executed until completion, immediately executing the interrupt for the other pin right afterward? (I know ARM Cortex M3 implements tail-chaining of interrupts)
- Or must there be a while loop that loops until all the pins have been cleared, clearing a pin after it has been processed?

maybe this will help:

http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm3s8962

Comment: In general, your ISR should immediately disable interrupts so that the ISR itself isn't interrupted. Be sure to reenable them at the conclusion of your ISR!

Comment: Thanks, that solves one part of the problem. The other part is that I don't want interrupts caused by the other pins to be ignored. Is this possible in the scenario I have described?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment: generally ISRs should take steps to prevent reentrancy.  In something like a PIC, this could be as simple as disabling the interrupt at the "top" of the ISR, and enabling the interrupt at the "bottom".  The M3's NVIC is a bit more complicated.  This white paper (http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/IntroToCortex-M3.pdf) states the following on p.7:

> The NVIC supports nesting (stacking) of interrupts, allowing an
>   interrupt to be serviced earlier by exerting higher priority. It also
>   supports dynamic reprioritisation of interrupts. Priority levels can
>   be changed by software during run time. Interrupts that are being
>   serviced are blocked from further activation until the interrupt
>   service routine is completed, so their priority can be changed without
>   risk of accidental re-entry.

The above discussion directly addresses the possibility of same interrupt reentrancy, and it also introduces the concept of prioritization to handle interrupts of higher priority interrupting your ISR.

This reference is pretty good: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/DUI0552A_cortex_m3_dgug.pdf.  On p. 4-9, you'll find instructions to enable/disable interrupts.  On page 4-6, you'll find a description of the Interrupt Clear-pending Registers.  Using these, you can determine what interrupts are pending. If you really want to get fancy with interrupt enable/disable control, check out the BASEPRI and BASEPRO_MAX registers.

Having said that, I'm not sure I agree with your statement that your question is relevant to any Cortex-M3.  Keil (my flavor of Cortex-M3) mentions that the EXTI (external interrupt controller) handles GPIO pin interrupts.  Interestingly, the ARM documentation briefly discusses "EXTI", but does not refer to it as a "controller" like the Keil STM32 documentation.  A quick google on "STM32 EXTI" yeilds lots of hits, a similar search on "Luminary EXTI" does not yield much.  Given that, I'm guessing that this particular controller is one of the peripheral devices that ARM leaves to 3rd parties.

This document
bolsters that view: http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00171190.pdf.  There are several AFIO_EXTI registers mentioned here.  These permit the mapping of GPIO lines to interrupts.  Unfortunately, I can't find anything similar in the Luminary documentation.

So...what does this mean? It looks like you only have port-level granularity for your interrupt.  Thus, your ISR will have to determine which pin transitioned (assuming your are looking for edges). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Cortex-M3, if two interrupts are the same priority (for all GPIO pins), the former will not be interrupted. The interrupt comes later will be in pending state.

When a GPIO interrupt occurs you can check the GPIO Interrupt Status for Rising/Falling IO0IntEnR/IO0IntEnF (depending on  ) for the corresponding bit to find the pin that causes the interrupt.

Comment: If the interrupt coming later is in the pending state, it is serviced immediately after the ISR has finished, granted that no interrupt of higher priority has been triggered?